# ImportError: undefined symbol: cudnnConvolutionBiasActivationForward

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I encountered the following error when trying to run a TensorFlow program:

```
$ python3 
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: cudnnConvolutionBiasActivationForward

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: cudnnConvolutionBiasActivationForward
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

System info:
Ubuntu 16.04
Cuda 8.0
cudnn 5.1
tensorflow-gpu version

Comment: It's not a great answer, but it looks like this problem has been fixed with reinstallation or force installs in the past: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12326

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12326), a force reinstall should do the trick or downgrading to a lower tensorflow version will work as well:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

One possible cause of this problem is if you installed both tensorflow-cpu and tensorflow-gpu.